# Polynomials of degree less than $n$ that agree at $n$ values

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

> Suppose $\deg(a(x))$ and $\deg(b(x))$ are both less than $n$.
>   If $a(c) = b(c)$ for $n$ values of $c$, prove that $a(x) = b(x)$.

This seems simple, since if the $a(c) = b(c)$ for $n$ values of $c$, then this implies that $a(x) = b(x)$ due to the definition of a polynomial. But, what does the degree have to do with this proof?

I'm stuck.

Comment: Due to the definition of a polynomial? Huh? Wha? Explain yourself.

Comment: Technically, yeah it is due to the definition of polynomial (over a field), but there is at least one major creative step along the way.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $d(x) = a(x) - b(x)$, you have that $d(c_i) = 0$ for $i = 1,2,\cdots, n$, thus $d(x) = r(x)(x-c_1)(x-c_2)\cdots (x-c_n)$, and $\text{deg}(d(x)) \geq n > n-1 \geq \text{deg}((a(x))$, thus this occurs only if $d(x) = k, \forall x, k$ is a constant. But $k = d(c_1) = 0 \to k = 0 \to d(x) = 0 \to a(x) = b(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

The degree is important: For example, $a(x) = x^2 + 1$ and $b(x) =x + 1$ agree at two $x$-values ($x = 0$ and $x = 1$) but they're certainly not the same.

There's a key fact is that a polynomial of degree $k-1$ is uniquely determined by its value at $k$ distinct $x$-values. That is, given $k$ points $(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2), \ldots, (x_k, y_k)$, there's a unique polynomial $p(x)$ such that $p(x_i) = y_i$.

If you think computationally, it shouldn't be hard to convince yourself that this is true. How you could get $k$ equations in $k$ unknowns, and what $k$ numbers uniquely determine a polynomial of degree $k - 1$?